# Width of last column extends beyond max value of chart, causes extra padding

Tags: highcharts

I have a datetime chart where I have a variable min/max range and variable pointRange. The start and end points of the data may end up such that there is an overlap with the min/max range. I've found in certain cases this causes there to be a large amount of padding at the end of the chart because it tries to fit in the last column. Ideally I think it should just cut off the last column the same way it does for the first column. Is there a workaround for this issue?

I've reproduced it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/uFswf/1/

```
$(function () {
var chart1;
$(document).ready(function () {
  chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart($.extend(true, {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'foo',
        zoomType: '',
        spacingRight: 20,
        spacingLeft: 20,
        events: {}
    },
    title: {
        text: "Test"
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: null
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: true
        },
        min: 150,
        max: 500,
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        startOnTick: true,
        showFirstLabel: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    credits:{
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointRange: 300,
            pointPlacement: 'between'
        },
        series: {
            animation: true,
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0
        }
    }, 
    series:[{
        type: 'column',
        data: [
            [100, 50],
            [400, 100]
        ]
    }]
   }));
  });
 });
```

Comment: Have you tried to set pointWidth ?http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointWidth

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to fix the issue.